# How to capture ageing field on four different fields

Tags: workflow, formula-field

I have a picklist named as Idea having values Inreview, new, need for information , completed

Also I have made 4 number fields Inreview, new ,need for information and completed.

I want to capture the no. of days the picklist value suppose inreview is in the inreview field, no. of days the new value is in new field, no. of days need for information is in need for information field and completed is in completed field.

Regards,
Kunal

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to have a date field for each of the stages.
 - Entered_InReview_Date
 - Entered_New_Date
 - Entered_Need_Info_Date
 - Entered_Completed_Date

Then use process builder to see if the stage changed to set the date in one of these fields. The only issue is if the stages can go back and forth but if not this should work. Then you can calculate the age at each stage.